# Why here array out of bound exception ocuur?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int m;
Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("limit of array start from 0");
m=obj.nextInt();

int[] array=new int[m];
int[] pro=new int[m];
int front=0;

int rear=m;

System.out.println("Array element entry");
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    array[i]=obj.nextInt(); 

System.out.println("size"+array.length);

array[front]=array[front]+array[rear];

for(int j=0;j<pro.length;j++)
    System.out.println(" the array"+array[j]);
```

Comment: Please. Formatting.

Comment: Syntax error. Please correct the question

Comment: You can use the curly brackets to format

Comment: Your for-loop has no backets.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing array[rear] in this case rear is == to the size of the array and is not a valid index.  Arrays go from 0 to (size - 1).

```
int rear = m - 1;
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int rear = m;
```

should be

```
int rear = m - 1;
```

Because Java arrays start at `0` and it is always out of bounds to attempt to access an element at `array.length`.

Also, you could use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) to print your array;

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```